# Identifying all types with some attribute

Tags: .net, reflection, custom-attributes

I have an issue with .Net reflection. The concept is fairly new to me and I'm exploring it with some test cases to see what works and what doesn't. I'm constructing an example wherein I populate a set of menus dynamically by scanning through my Types' attributes.

Basically, I want to find every type in my main namespace that declares 'SomeAttribute' (doesn't matter what it is, it doesn't have any members at present). What I've done is:

```
    For Each itemtype As Type In Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes
        If itemtype.IsDefined(Type.GetType("SomeAttribute"), False) Then
            'do something with the type
        End If
    Next
```

This crashes the application on startup - the first type it identifies is MyApplication which is fairly obviously not what I want. Is there a right and proper way to look for all the 'real' 'sensible' types - i.e. classes that I've defined - within the current assembly?

Comment: I've just found something - Assembly.GetExportedTypes is said to get classes visible to the outside world. I'm wondering whether this would work better, but I'd still like to make sure I'm not barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: What's wrong with `MyApplication`? It should make no difference. Which exception do you get? There seems to be nothing in your code that should crash in the case of `MyApplication`.

Comment: Looking at your functionality requirements, wouldn´t you be better of with ´.Net Attributes´?

Comment: Please add to the question an exception that you are getting.

Comment: It's an invalidoperation - the cause is that I've just carelessly identified the type and it's being passed as nothing.

Marvin - I am confused by your question. What do you mean that's different to what I'm already using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that `IsDefined()` fails since `Type.GetType("SomeAttribute")` returns null. Try adding the namespace to the attribute name:

```
Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeAttribute")
```

Comment: Thanks, the cause is blindingly obvious. Thanks to all the other responders as it's all useful information, this one is *technically* the answer however - the root cause was my own carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little Linq

```
var list =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).
                        Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0);
```